# Moment-generating function of $m$ independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent variables, each of them has a Discrete uniform distribution between $0$ and $m$, $m= \left( 2,3,4,,... \right)$.
>
> Let $Y$ be a random variable which is defined by $Y = X_1 + X_2 +...+X_n$.
>
> What is the Moment-generating function of $Y$?

I do know that since the $X_i$s are independent, the function is a sum of all the moment generating functions of the $X_i$s. I also know that each function is essentially the expected value of $e^{tx}$. However, here I'm lost.

Comment: "since the $X_i$s are independent, the function is a sum of all the moment generating functions of the $X_i$" What you mean by that is unclear but almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The moment-generating function of a sum of independent random variables is the product of their moment generating functions.

To a large extent, that's the point of using the moment-generating function at all; the transform method turns the convolution that is the density/probability function of the sum into a pointwise product.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the actual function?

Comment: Calculating the moment-generating function for a discrete uniform distribution is just a finite geometric series. You should be able to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

$Ee^{tY}=[\frac 1 {m+1} \frac {e^{t(m+1)}-1} {e^{t-1}}]^{n}$ for $t \neq 0$, $1$ for $t=1$. I have used the formula for a geometric sum as well as the fact that the MGF of a sum of independent random variables is the product of the individual MGF's.

Comment: Thank you. Why $\frac{1}{m+1}$ and not $\frac{1}{m}$?

Comment: @Alan How many numbers are there from $0$ to $m$ (both included)? There are $m+1$ of them not $m$.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be fair, I HAVE NOT down graded your answer, but rather upgraded it. :-)